# Mercurial equivalent of "cvs -nq update"

Tags: mercurial, cvs

For those unfamiliar with CVS, `cvs -nq update` shows something like this.

```
$ cvs -nq update
M file_changed_locally.c
U file_changed_remotely.c
C file_with_conflicts.c
? untracked_file.c
```

I know I can use `hg status` to get locally modified files, and `hg incoming` to list changesets yet to be pulled, but is there a way to get a report like the above that combines local and remote changes at the file level?

An acceptable (but worse) substitute would be something that shows the relevant data for between `hg pull` and `hg update`.

Comment: I don't know any but if everything else fails, you can write a plugin to do that. It's Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I ended up with:

```
$ hg pull && hg status --rev .:
```

It lists files that will be touched by `hg update`.

Answer (score 2):

[`hg summary --remote`](http://www.selenic.com/hg/help/summary) will give an overview of you repo compared against the parent of your working copy and the default paths for incoming/outgoing changes.

It will show something like:

```
parent: 14344:e1db8a00188b tip
 win32.py: more explicit definition of _STD_ERROR_HANDLE
branch: default
commit: 1 modified
update: (current)
remote: 1 or more incoming
mq:     1 unapplied
```

However, it does not give a list of files.

Answer (score 0):

Although there's no unified command to do this, you can stack two commands up on the command line or using a batch file/shell script.

If you have access to GNU utilities you can stack up Tim's response with `hg st`:

`> hg st; hg summary --remote`

which gives you something like this:

[image]

If you have a Windows CMD shell you can use this to get a very similar result:

`> hg st & hg summary --remote`